# Drag pictures/files into nodes

Tags: node-editor, hdri

How can I easily, and fast, swap HDRI files in the environment tab without opening up a File Browser that covers the whole screen?

[image]

**More explanation:**
Just switched from Cinema 4D to Blender 2.8 (and I already love Blender a lot more). The only thing I miss is the workflow that Greyscalegorillas ´HDRI Rig´ had. I've noticed it's easy to set up a similar workflow in Blender, if only this worked: Dragging pictures/files from the File Browser into the Shader Editor (and easily replacing HDRI files to change environments etc). At the moment, this creates a new node???? Instead of pasting the name..

Comment: I think, you should post this on [devtalk forum](https://devtalk.blender.org), not here. You can post it in [UI paper cuts](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-ui-paper-cuts/2596/1087) tread, or create a new one.

Comment: Anyway, i've posted it